# I only want to use wireshark's dissector function, and I need to close the Qt interface

Tags: ssl, wireshark

I only want to use wireshark's dissector function, and I need to close the Qt interface. How can I do it? I want to make it a executable program only with dissector function, to decrypt the tls application data.

Comment: You could use [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html)?  This is the command-line equivalent to Wireshark and it should be able to decrypt the tls traffic just like Wireshark can.

Comment: Tshark can decrypt the tls traffic?

Comment: If provide the sslkeylogfile , is it possible for me to use tshark to decrypt tls? Can I wirte the plaintext to the another pcap file? For that, I want to get the decryption sample. Thanks a lot.@ChristopherMaynard

Comment: Yes, `tshark` can decrypt the tls traffic just as Wireshark can.  You can try it: `tshark -r tlsfile.pcap -o tls.keylog_file:path/to/sslkeylogfile/sslkeylogfile.txt --color`.  While you can view the decrypted packets, I'm not sure if it's possible to save the decrypted packets.  There are Wireshark TLS experts  over at https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/ so you might want to try asking your question there .

Answer (score 0):

As others said, use `tshark`.

```
$ tshark -r /tmp/out.pcap -t ad -o "ssl.keylog_file: /tmp/ssl.keylog_file" \
 -o "ssl.desegment_ssl_records: TRUE" -o "ssl.desegment_ssl_application_data: TRUE" \
 -o "ssl.debug_file:/tmp/ssl-debug.log" -Y 'http or http2'
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
   10 2022-10-12 13:19:06.132362635 192.168.122.230 → 192.168.122.1 HTTP2 123 SETTINGS, WINDOW_UPDATE
   11 2022-10-12 13:19:06.132520145 192.168.122.1 → 192.168.122.230 HTTP2 119 Magic
   12 2022-10-12 13:19:06.132565302 192.168.122.1 → 192.168.122.230 HTTP2 122 SETTINGS
   13 2022-10-12 13:19:06.132572597 192.168.122.1 → 192.168.122.230 HTTP2 108 WINDOW_UPDATE
   15 2022-10-12 13:19:06.132728591 192.168.122.230 → 192.168.122.1 HTTP2 104 SETTINGS
   16 2022-10-12 13:19:06.133008405 192.168.122.1 → 192.168.122.230 HTTP2 140 HEADERS
   17 2022-10-12 13:19:06.133038924 192.168.122.1 → 192.168.122.230 HTTP2 104 SETTINGS
   19 2022-10-12 13:19:06.134550933 192.168.122.230 → 192.168.122.1 HTTP2 202 HEADERS, DATA
   23 2022-10-12 13:19:06.135134429 192.168.122.230 → 192.168.122.1 HTTP2 112 GOAWAY
```